# Google GeoCoding always return error

Tags: javascript, java, google-api, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm using google Geocoding API to convert adresses to coordinates. I tried using JavaScript and also with [JAVA services provided by Google](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java).

I've setup a Google project from the developpers console, **I've activated the Google Maps Geocoding API**, and I've create two API keys (a browser key for the JS, and a server key for the JAVA)

With all this setup, It worked exactly 8 times (from my API quotas) and since, on every query, the API keep returning this error:

```
{
    "error_message": "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=_",
    "results": [],
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I tried to activate ALL the APIs under "API Google Maps" on the Google APIs home page, it change nothing.

Anyone came across the same problem ? How did you solved this ?

Comment: So I'm still stucked... No one have any clue why Google is locking me ?

Comment: Try disable and enable API again. Check a daily quota to be sure that it's > 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after posting on Google forums and as @xomena mention it, my daily quota was set to 0, don't know why...

If you get the same message (which isn't very clear) take a look at your daily quota ;)